# How to print the 2 most repeated strings in an array

Tags: javascript, typescript

First of all I apologize this may be trivial but I'm stuck, I search in an array the string that repeats the most and print the 2 that repeat the most.
I have wanted to do Case or multiple if, but I also get the idea of a map(), in short I do not find an efficient way to implement it.
thank you very much in advance

```js
const clientes=['cliente1','cliente2', 'cliente3', 'cliente2', 'cliente3', 'cliente4'];
for(let x = 0; x < clientes.length; x++) 
{

}
console.log('CLIENTES', clientes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop and count. your approach goes to right direction.

```js
let counts = {};
const clientes = ['cliente1','cliente2', 'cliente3', 'cliente2', 'cliente3', 'cliente4'];

clientes.forEach(function (x) { counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0) + 1; });
console.log(counts)
```